# Data Factory copy pipeline from API

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We use Azure Data Factory copy pipeline to transfer data from REST api's to a Azure SQL Database and it is doing some strange things. Because we loop over a set of API's that need to be transferred the mapping is empty from the copy activity.
But for one API the automatic mapping is going wrong, the destination table is created with all the needed columns and correct datatypes based on the received metadata. When we run the pipeline for that specific API, the following message is showed.

```
{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=SchemaMappingFailedInHierarchicalToTabularStage,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to process hierarchical to tabular stage, error message: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.\r\nParameter name: ticks,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy data1", "details": [] }
```

As a test we did do the mapping for that API manually by using the "Import Schema" option on the Mapping page. there we see that all the fields are correctly mapped. We execute the pipeline again using the mapping and everything is working fine.
But of course, we don't want to use a manually mapping because it is used in a loop for different API's also.

Comment: you can have schema mapping defined even if you are copying from let's say generic dataset. 
define schema directly in a json. That solved me this kind of problem. 
(ofc if your different API's return same column structure

Comment: @DraganB thanks for the reply, do you have an example on how to define the schema mapping in the json? I suppose that i have to define all the possible columns that all the api's will return?

Comment: can you add na example of your json?

Comment: The table structure of the different API's are different. When defining the mapping for that API in the json. That API is working but all the others are failing because he want to map columns that are not existing. So i think i need to define a custom flow for that api that is failing

Comment: You can't automap from different source to same target. If columns are missing in the target it will fail (if they are missing in the soure it's fine)